# can't send email in laravel using gmail smtp

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, laravel-5.1

sending emails with laravel using gmail smtp was working fine in homestead
but in production i get this error

```
[Swift_TransportException]                                                    
  Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]
```

I think  there is a problem with the ip because this message `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: Where are you hosting it? Can you connect to other services from there? What is the code you're using to send the email like?

Comment: I'm hosting in OVH , i don't how to use their mail

Comment: You could try this from bash to see if you can use gmail from your host: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472520

Answer (score 1):

In your root terminal use the command
sudo ufw allow in "Postfix Submission"

This will enable your port 587 for SMTP

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used in my .env file to send email via gmail:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

EDIT: And you need to activate something in your gmail settings: 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: me too the same , I think the problem with the host

Comment: I edited my message, did you follow "Allowing less secure apps to access your account" in your gmail settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In `config/mail.php`**

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => 'batman@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Batman'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'bat',
    'password' => 'bat@123',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

);
```

**In `views/emails`** (`welcome.blade.php`)

```
<h1>Hi</h1>

<p>No Nothing to tell</p>
```

**In code**

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {
    $message->to('spiderman@gmail. com', 'Spider Man')->subject('Come to Party');
});
```

> > **Make sure Two-Step Verification is not activated in above email**

Comment: thanks Man I sent emails too Many times and it worked fine (in development), now in production  
the problem seems to be with the host

Comment: No , i will create a new gmail account to test

Comment: ok. make sure no verification. If answer helps you dont forget to accept this

Comment: after some reasearch I found this command
**telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25**
which outputs

**Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c05::1b...
Trying 173.194.67.27...**
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
 it means the configuration of ip is bad